# Rails 4 rspec test fails before code is run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

EDIT: My initial assumption was incorrect. It seemed like my test was hitting its assertions before it even finished running all of its code blocks, but what was really happening was, I was running my full test suite and I was getting the output from a different test that was hitting the same controller action. I ran the individual test below and found that I wasn't even hitting the controller. I had to correct my route in the test. All set now.

Rest of original post:

> NOTE: to make things easier to read, this is NOT the complete code

My test with 'activerecord-import' gem

./spec/features/importer/importer_property_list_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'import property list data to database' do
  puts "Enter test"
  before(:each) do
    visit 'importers#import_property_list'
  end

  let!(:first_cash_account) { FactoryGirl.build(:first_cash_account) }
  let!(:last_cash_account) { FactoryGirl.build(:last_cash_account) }
  let!(:first_entity) { FactoryGirl.build(:first_entity) }
  let!(:last_entity) { FactoryGirl.build(:last_entity) }

  context 'uploading property list file, causes data to be importet to database' do
    it 'creates cash accounts' do

      puts "hit first test"
      expect(CashAccount.first.code).to eql(first_cash_account.code)
      expect(CashAccount.last.code).to eql(last_cash_account.code)
    end

    it 'creates entities' do

      puts "hit second test"
      expect(Entity.first.name).to eql(first_entity.name)
      expect(Entity.first.cash_account.code).to eql(first_cash_account.code)
      expect(Entity.last.name).to eql(last_entity.name)
    end
  end
end
```

My controller
./app/controllers/importers_controller.rb

```
class ImportersController < ApplicationController
 def index
  end

  def show
  end

  def import_property_list
    puts "Enter import"
    cash_accounts = []
    excel = property_list_excel
    (4..excel.last_row).each do |row|
      code = eighth_col(excel, row)
      cash_account = CashAccount.new(:code => code)
      name = eleventh_col(excel, row)
      name = remove_non_breaking_space(name)
      cash_account.entities.build(:name => name)
      cash_accounts << cash_account
    end
    CashAccount.import cash_accounts, recursive: true, :validates => false
    puts "Finish import"
  end
end
```

This is my output in my console

[image]

NOTE: the first test only passes because of my factory_girl's factory association which creates CashAccount records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, something that looked a little out of place: shouldn't this be in the before(:each) block? i normally don't leave set up code in the open like that.

```
let!(:first_cash_account) { FactoryGirl.build(:first_cash_account) }
  let!(:last_cash_account) { FactoryGirl.build(:last_cash_account) }
  let!(:first_entity) { FactoryGirl.build(:first_entity) }
  let!(:last_entity) { FactoryGirl.build(:last_entity) }
```

Basically this is saying that there are no Entity records created. Where are you creating the entity records? in the block here: `(4..excel.last_row).each do |row|` but is the block even running? Look to see whether there are any legitimate values in `excel = property_list_excel` - please check that excel is not nil? and also check whether the block is actually looping through:

```
def import_property_list
    puts "Enter import"
    cash_accounts = []
    excel = property_list_excel
    (4..excel.last_row).each do |row|
      code = eighth_col(excel, row)
      puts "IT's ITERATING THROUGH*********************" # <----------------- add this line
      cash_account = CashAccount.new(:code => code)
      name = eleventh_col(excel, row)
      name = remove_non_breaking_space(name)
      cash_account.entities.build(:name => name)
      cash_accounts << cash_account
    end
    CashAccount.import cash_accounts, recursive: true, :validates => false
    puts "Finish import"
  end
end
```

## edit: - the real problem

are you sure the link is actually visiting via this type of syntax: visit 'importers#import_property_list' ---> try using the named path or a proper url instead. I'm not sure you can use that syntax when visiting a webpage and that's probably your problem i think. e.g. try import_property_etc_etc_list_named_path –

that should help pinpoint the problem?

Comment: I am mistaken, a different test outputs the "Enter/Finish import". You are on the right track, when I run just this test file, it doesn't even hit the controller action at all it seems.

Comment: @wsgb are you sure the link is actually visiting via this type of syntax: visit 'importers#import_property_list' ---> try using the named path or a proper url instead. I'm not sure you can use that syntax when visiting a webpage and that's probably your problem i think. e.g. try import_property_etc_etc_list_named_path

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly the problem. If you can add that to your post, I'll mark your post as the answer.

Comment: @wsgb glad you could debug. best wishes

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `FactoryGirl.build` instead of `FactoryGirl.create` in your let statements.  This means that the objects only exist in memory but don't actually persist in the database, so when you call `Entity.first` their are no entities in the db.

Comment: The controller action "import_property_list" is what creates and persists the Entity objects to the database. cash_account.entities.build(params) is what creates the Entity objects which are then appended to an array. The CashAccount.import persists all of those records. The FactoryGirl.build has the values that I am asserting with the database records.

Comment: Did you try it with create and it didn't work?  I didn't realize you were visiting import_property_list before every test.

Comment: Using create would have defeated the purpose of that specific test. The test is designed to confirm the persistence of the objects via the controller action. If we just created the database records off the top, then our test would pass without actually testing if our controller action worked like it was supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the route in my test from

```
visit 'importers#import_property_list'
```

to

```
visit import_property_list_importers_path
```